# PHP multidimensional array (or object) to JSON

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, json

I have 2 DB tables. table 2 is relational to table 1.

In php I am building a multidimensional array to hold the data key/values.

because PHP needs to have unique "keys" MY JSON is looking like this:

```
[
{
    "packs": {
        "9": {
            "characters": {
                "40": {
                    "id": "40",
                    "title": "Jack Bauer",
                    "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "41": {
                    "id": "41",
                    "title": "Chloe O'Brian",
                    "pic": "ffb6acc8e3.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "42": {
                    "id": "42",
                    "title": "Tony Almeida",
                    "pic": "23f199e223.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "7": {
            "characters": {
                "7": {
                    "id": "7",
                    "title": "Elvis Presley",
                    "pic": "78300767ad.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "16": {
                    "id": "16",
                    "title": "Madonna",
                    "pic": "70663a42f7.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "17": {
                    "id": "17",
                    "title": "Lady Gaga",
                    "pic": "c5099c619b.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "21": {
                    "id": "21",
                    "title": "Pink Floyd",
                    "pic": "52ddce314a.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "22": {
                    "id": "22",
                    "title": "Led Zeppelin",
                    "pic": "84cd58ada3.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "31": {
                    "id": "31",
                    "title": "The Beatles",
                    "pic": "bd22a4d648.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "32": {
                    "id": "32",
                    "title": "Foo Fighters",
                    "pic": "250fb6ecec.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "33": {
                    "id": "33",
                    "title": "Bananarama",
                    "pic": "da7c2b56cf.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "35": {
                    "id": "35",
                    "title": "Boney-M",
                    "pic": "3cbdada38b.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "38": {
                    "id": "38",
                    "title": "The Spice Girls",
                    "pic": "4751f0fbb7.jpeg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "39": {
                    "id": "39",
                    "title": "Girls Aloud",
                    "pic": "644dcf71ca.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "8": {
            "characters": {
                "9": {
                    "id": "9",
                    "title": "Keith Lemon",
                    "pic": "ff6ef10853.jpg.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "23": {
                    "id": "23",
                    "title": "Fearne Cotton",
                    "pic": "0d038b6516.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "24": {
                    "id": "24",
                    "title": "Holly Willoughby",
                    "pic": "836fc4184c.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "30": {
                    "id": "30",
                    "title": "Rufus Hound",
                    "pic": "062bee9602.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "characters": {
                "5": {
                    "id": "5",
                    "title": "Tom Cruise",
                    "pic": "ff296fafb9.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "10": {
                    "id": "10",
                    "title": "Linda Lovelace",
                    "pic": "ac1bea43d3.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "15": {
                    "id": "15",
                    "title": "Gwyneth Paltrow",
                    "pic": "43a22d7240.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "44": {
                    "id": "44",
                    "title": "Errol Flynn",
                    "pic": "cea17c1275.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "45": {
                    "id": "45",
                    "title": "Halle Berry",
                    "pic": "752b5c92c5.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "characters": {
                "4": {
                    "id": "4",
                    "title": "Donald Duck",
                    "pic": "8d367f41b1.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "6": {
                    "id": "6",
                    "title": "Mickey Mouse",
                    "pic": "8d9629c115.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "28": {
                    "id": "28",
                    "title": "Pluto",
                    "pic": "fb2c0e2dd0.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "29": {
                    "id": "29",
                    "title": "Minnie Mouse",
                    "pic": "378760ff77.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "36": {
                    "id": "36",
                    "title": "Cinderella",
                    "pic": "a7e4888213.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "37": {
                    "id": "37",
                    "title": "Snow White",
                    "pic": "a9cf05a857.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "4": {
            "characters": {
                "3": {
                    "id": "3",
                    "title": "Bill Clinton",
                    "pic": "03c6567ddb.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "11": {
                    "id": "11",
                    "title": "Margaret Thatcher",
                    "pic": "91c9fa9fd0.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "13": {
                    "id": "13",
                    "title": "David Cameron",
                    "pic": "a689984360.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "14": {
                    "id": "14",
                    "title": "Nick Clegg",
                    "pic": "3243e298e5.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "26": {
                    "id": "26",
                    "title": "George Bush JR",
                    "pic": "46296f6b0e.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "27": {
                    "id": "27",
                    "title": "Ed Milliband",
                    "pic": "66f1449994.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "5": {
            "characters": {
                "8": {
                    "id": "8",
                    "title": "Stephen Hawking",
                    "pic": "b8c4f17530.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "18": {
                    "id": "18",
                    "title": "Alan Turing",
                    "pic": "82b4d84e35.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "19": {
                    "id": "19",
                    "title": "Albert Einstein",
                    "pic": "a6cd74dbaa.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "34": {
                    "id": "34",
                    "title": "Brian Cox (prof)",
                    "pic": "92b6005de9.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "43": {
                    "id": "43",
                    "title": "Richard Feynman",
                    "pic": "5de10d1128.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "characters": {
                "12": {
                    "id": "12",
                    "title": "Jeff Koons",
                    "pic": "8e3ca5f497.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "20": {
                    "id": "20",
                    "title": "Salvador Dali",
                    "pic": "b5bafb7934.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "25": {
                    "id": "25",
                    "title": "Rembrandt",
                    "pic": "73e2710029.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                },
                "49": {
                    "id": "49",
                    "title": "Vincent Van Gough",
                    "pic": "6ee455ab28.jpg",
                    "gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

I am trying to solve a problem that my iOS dev wants sorting... apparently the "{"packs":{"9": " 9 is wrong and does not follow the key:value JSON structure. How on earth do I create a correct PHP array or object for that matter with the unique identifier for each of the result sets from DB table 1?

the result should be structured like this:

data_db_1:1

data_db_2:id
 data_db_2:title
 data_db_2:pic
 data_db_2:gender

data_db_1:2

data_db_2:id
  data_db_2:title
  data_db_2:pic
  data_db_2:gender

data_db_1:3

data_db_2:id
 data_db_2:title
 data_db_2:pic
 data_db_2:gender

data_db_1:4
   data_db_2:id
   data_db_2:title
   data_db_2:pic
   data_db_2:gender

and look like this:

```
     {
"id": "9",
"title": "24",
"credits": "100",
"character": [
    {
        "id": "50",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "50",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "50",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "50",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
]
```

}

I cant find allot on the web relating to this. The only way I can think to solve it is to create each part seperately from PHP arrays using json_encode() and echo and a mess of concat. Surely json_encode() should be capable of creating correct JSON from a simple php array, a complex php multidimensional array or a PHP object without breaking a sweat???

---

my php function to do this as requested:

```
$data_ar = output_pack_data($pack_id);

echo "[".json_encode($data_ar)."]";         // first bit of dirty here

function output_pack_data($pack_id = false)
{
global $db;

$output_keys = true; //false;

if($pack_id != false)
{
    $q = "WHERE id='{$pack_id}' AND active = '1'";                                                          // select the relevant pack ID
}
else
{
    $q = "WHERE active='1' ORDER BY order_num ASC";                                                         // select all pack ids
}

$rs = $db->rs("whoami_packs",$q);

$pack_obj = new stdClass();                                                                                 // declare new std class object here......

$data = array();                                                                                            // prep new array to hold the data

while($rs && $r = $db->fetch($rs))                                                                          // loop thorugh each pack id
{
    $pack_obj->packs->id = $r->id;                                                                      // add the pack title
    $pack_obj->packs->title = $r->title;                                                                        // add the pack title
    $pack_obj->packs->credits = $r->credits;                                                                    // add the required credits to access 

    $packs_rs = $db->rs("whoami_characters","WHERE pack_id='{$r->id}' AND active = '1'");                   // get the character data relevant for this pack

    $i=0;

    while($packs_rs && $pack_r = $db->fetch($packs_rs))                                                     // loop through the character data
    {   
        $id = $r->id;

        if($output_keys == false)
        {
            $data['packs'][$r->id]['characters'][$pack_r->id][$pack_r->title][$pack_r->pic][$pack_r->gender] = true;    // build the array
        }
        else
        {
            $data['packs'][$r->id]['characters'][$pack_r->id]['id'] = $pack_r->id;                  // build the array
            $data['packs'][$r->id]['characters'][$pack_r->id]['title'] = str_out($pack_r->title);                   // build the array
            $data['packs'][$r->id]['characters'][$pack_r->id]['pic'] = $pack_r->pic;
            $data['packs'][$r->id]['characters'][$pack_r->id]['gender'] = ($pack_r->gender = 'm') ? "Male" : "Female";
        }
    }
}

return $data;                                                                                               // return the array
```

}

Comment: If your developer is saying that the first JSON sample is wrong, then [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) says otherwise.

Comment: How does the array look, how do you fill it with the data from the tables?

Comment: Your first JSON looks fine. You can convert arrays to json using php's `jsonencode()` function.

Comment: yes, i know!! but apparently the "6": { is wrong, ie the int seperators... This has been argued all day so far.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson  yes that what i am using

Comment: @Nick It isn't wrong. It just isn't. *However* I think that in order for your iOS dev to be satisfied what you need is [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array-values)

Comment: the question is not about "Valid" JSON so much, its about how to present a multidimensioal array from PHP in JSON without the "9": {

Comment: @Nick Well because you are retrieving the values from a DB driver that is presumably returning all data as strings (this is quite common in PHP) the created arrays are being created as *associative arrays with numeric string keys* rather than indexed arrays. Try changing `$data['packs'][$r->id]['characters'][$pack_r->id]['id'] = $pack_r->id;` to `$data['packs'][(int) $r->id]['characters'][(int) $pack_r->id]['id'] = $pack_r->id;` (and adjust the other similar line accordingly

Comment: @DaveRandom nice idea, but returns exactly the same. JSON is really just a string with encoding, it cares not what tpye of data is within its values....

Comment: @Nick I've just figured out what the problem is. An array must be *zero-indexed and contiguously keyed* in order for it to be converted correctly, otherwise PHP's JSON encoding algorithm converts it to an object with numeric string keys. [Consider this](http://codepad.org/TadroYeM). So as I suggested earlier, it looks like `array_values()` is the answer, or to construct a 0-indexed array in the first place.

Comment: @DaveRandom Seems like we found it around the same time! see my answer.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that json_encode() will ignore the key values if they are a simple incrementing counter....

this function:

```
function output_pack_data($pack_id = false)
{
global $db;

$output_keys = true; //false;

if($pack_id != false)
{
    $q = "WHERE id='{$pack_id}' AND active = '1'";                                                          // select the relevant pack ID
}
else
{
    $q = "WHERE active='1' ORDER BY order_num ASC";                                                         // select all pack ids
}

$rs = $db->rs("whoami_packs",$q);

$data = array();                                                                                            // prep new array to hold the data

$i = 0;    // AHA!

while($rs && $r = $db->fetch($rs))                                                                          // loop through each pack id
{
    $data[$i]['pack_id'] = $r->id;  
    $data[$i]['title'] = $r->title;                                                                     // add the pack title
    $data[$i]['credits'] = $r->credits;                                                                 // add the required credits to access 

    $chars_rs = $db->rs("whoami_characters","WHERE pack_id='{$r->id}' AND active = '1'");                   // get the character data relevant for this pack

    $ii = 0;           // AHA!

    while($chars_rs && $char_r = $db->fetch($chars_rs))                                                     // loop through the character data
    {   
        if($output_keys == false)
        {
            $data[$i]['characters'][$ii][$char_r->title][$char_r->pic][$char_r->gender] = true; // build the array
        }
        else
        {
            $data[(int)$i]['characters'][(int)$ii]['id'] = str_out($char_r->id);                    // build the array
            $data[(int)$i]['characters'][(int)$ii]['title'] = str_out($char_r->title);                  // build the array
            $data[(int)$i]['characters'][(int)$ii]['pic'] = $char_r->pic;
            $data[(int)$i]['characters'][(int)$ii]['gender'] = ($char_r->gender = 'm') ? "Male" : "Female";
        }
        $ii++;
    }

    $i++;
}

return $data;                                                                                               // return the array
```

}

will return the desired result. Odd that and no mention of it in the documentation! oh well, sorted for now! Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.... note the use of (int) to make sure the $i or $ii counters are correct integers. Using the DB IDs in this case will not work and they will get added to the output.

Comment: this link will show it clearly: http://codepad.org/TadroYeM as noted in DaveRandoms comment above (or below ;) )

Answer (score 1):

There's some superfluous code in the function. And when you have non-consecutive (numerical) indices json_encode will not use an [x,y,z] encoding but an object notation.
Apparently your colleague wants the IDs as properties of each object not as the key to an object. Therefore just drop referencing the array element via its id but first create the complete array then append it to its parent via $parent[]. This way you get an array with sequential numeric ids -> json_encode() creates an array notation.
(untested, i'm too lazy to build sql test data from the json output provided in the original question)

```
function output_pack_data($pack_id=false)
{
    global $db;
    $data = array();

    if($pack_id != false) {
        $q = "WHERE id='{$pack_id}' AND active = '1'";
    }
    else {
        $q = "WHERE active='1' ORDER BY order_num ASC";
    }

    $rs_packs = $db->rs("whoami_packs", $q);    
    while($rs_packs && ($rec_pack=$db->fetch($rs_packs)) ) {
        $pack = array(
            'id'=>$rec_pack->id,
            'title'=>$rec_pack->title,
            'credits'=>$rec_pack->credits,
            'characters'=>array()
        );

        $rs_chars = $db->rs("whoami_characters","WHERE pack_id='{$pack->id}' AND active = '1'");
        while($rs_chars && ($rec_char=$db->fetch($rs_chars)) ) {
            $pack['characters'][] = array(
                'id' => $rec_char->id,
                'title' => str_out($rec_char->title),
                'pic' => $rec_char->pic,
                'gender' => 'm'==$rec_char->gender ? "Male" : "Female"
            );
        }
        $data[] = $pack;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

And please have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is a comment and not an answer (again).

I think what the iOS developer (such as myself) is saying is that you are using the id of each object to define each object, and not a key.

Your example and your developer's expected output are both correct, however it's the actual structure of the information that's the issue.

If you head over to http://json.org/example.html to see some examples of JSON data structuring it might be made a little clearer.

Let's look at this in XML. If you convert the following JSON into XML:

```
[
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
},
{
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
}
]
```

You will be left with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <1>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Jack Bauer</title>
        <pic>68bcbe014c.jpg</pic>
        <gender>Male</gender>
    </1>
    <2>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Jack Bauer</title>
        <pic>68bcbe014c.jpg</pic>
        <gender>Male</gender>
    </2>
</xml>
```

Simply put, although it is correctly structured in both cases, the data placement is not correct. the <1> and <2> nodes should be the same key, this principle follows most standards (such as RSS).

Looking at your developer's requirements, he wants (in JSON and XML examples):

```
{
"character": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Jack Bauer",
        "pic": "68bcbe014c.jpg",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
]
}
```

and as XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<character>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Jack Bauer</title>
    <pic>68bcbe014c.jpg</pic>
    <gender>Male</gender>
</character>
<character>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Jack Bauer</title>
    <pic>68bcbe014c.jpg</pic>
    <gender>Male</gender>
</character>
</xml>
```

The second examples are clearly structured more efficiently, since the key (character) defines each value, and not the id of each value itself.

Comment: "Looking at your developer's requirements, he wants (in JSON and XML examples):" LOL

Answer (score 0):

Using the option `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` (Available since PHP 5.3.0, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)) will force `json_encode` to create a valid JSON Object